# How to preallocate and fill a slice of pointers in a go-idiomatic way?

Tags: go, slice

http://play.golang.org/p/j-Y0mQzTdP

```
package main

import "fmt"

type UselessStruct struct {
    a int
    b int
}

func main() {
    mySlice := make([]*UselessStruct, 5)
    for i := 0; i != 5; i++ {
        mySlice = append(mySlice, &UselessStruct{})
    }

    fmt.Println(mySlice)
}
```

Outputs: `[<nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> 0xc010035160 0xc010035170 0xc010035180 0xc010035190 0xc0100351a0]`

What i would like to do, is preallocate memory for 5 UselessStructs, stored as pointers. If i declare a slice of struct values eq:

```
mySlice := make([]UselessStruct, 5)
```

then this creates 5 empty structs - appending doesn't replace the empty structs, but rather keeps on adding to the slice, so the end result with this code:

http://play.golang.org/p/zBYqGVO85h

```
package main

import "fmt"

type UselessStruct struct {
    a int
    b int
}

func main() {
    mySlice := make([]UselessStruct, 5)
    for i := 0; i != 5; i++ {
        mySlice = append(mySlice, UselessStruct{})
    }

    fmt.Println(mySlice)
}
```

is: `[{0 0} {0 0} {0 0} {0 0} {0 0} {0 0} {0 0} {0 0} {0 0} {0 0}]`

**What is the the go-idiomatic way to preallocate and fill slices?**

Answer (score 56, accepted):

For your first example, I would do:

```
mySlice := make([]*UselessStruct, 5)
for i := range mySlice {
     mySlice[i] = new(UselessStruct)
}
```

The issue you are facing in both examples is you are appending to a slice that is already the correct length. If you set `mySlice := make([]*UselessStruct, 5)`, you are asking for a slice of nil pointers of length 5. If you append one pointer, it now has length 6.

Instead, you want to use `mySlice := make([]*UselessStruct, 0, 5)`. This creates a slice of length 0 but capacity 5. Each time you append it will add one to the length but it won't reallocate until you exceed the slice's capacity.

```
mySlice := make([]*UselessStruct, 0, 5)
for i := 0; i != 5; i++ {
    mySlice = append(mySlice, &UselessStruct{})
}
// mySlice is [0xc010035160 0xc010035170 0xc010035180 0xc010035190 0xc0100351a0]
```

Both of my examples will work as you expect but I recommend the first one for purely style reasons.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "for purely style reasons"? Personally, I find the `append` solution more logical and readable because it avoids intermediate states where some of the elements have zero values. Also, isn't filling the slice with zero values initially wasted effort?

Comment: All memory that is allocated in Go is zeroed out. So there is no wasted effort.

Answer (score 9):

There are two ways to do this. One is by pre-allocating the slots as you did.
But instead of using `append`, you simply index into one of the existing slots:

```
mySlice[i] = &UselessStruct{}
```

The second is to use the 'overloaded' verion of `make`. You specify zero length, but a capacity of 5.

```
package main

type T struct {
    A int
    B int
}

func main() {
    mySlice := make([]*T, 0, 5)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        mySlice = append(mySlice, &T{1, 2})
    }
}
```

`mySlice := make([]*T, 0, 5)` initializes the slice with a length of zero, but it still pre-allocates enough space for 5 entries.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you need pointers? Your struct has a zero value so:

```
mySlice := make([]UselessStruct, 5) // has memory preallocated for 5 UselessStructs.
```

And since slices are reference types you effectively have 5 pointers to those 5 UselessStructs.

If you need to get a reference to an individual struct to pass around then you can just so

```
myStruct := &mySlice[0]
```

And now you have a pointer to a `UselessStruct` to use as you see fit. It's far less code than you have and leverages Go's zero value feature.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete: append works with nil slice so, you don't need to create the slice with make, you can just append element to it.

```
var mySlice []*UselessStruct
for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
    mySlice = append(mySlice, &UselessStruct{})
}
```

This will do the same as previous example without pre-allocation, but if you know the size, you rather use something like this one:

```
mySlice := make([]*UselessStruct, 0, 5)
for i := range mySlice {
    mySlice[i] = &UselessStruct{}
}
```

This may avoid some reallocation.